# Outlook 2010 remove attachment of specific type (e.g. *.txt) when sending email

Tags: email, outlook, attachment, outlook-2010

I've a question about Outlook 2010.
When an user wants to send an email with an attachment of type *.txt I'd like to remove this attachment when he hit the button [Send].

I'm looking for setting a filter in the FilterDialog or setting a registry key.

I've found something like: https://chornsokun.wordpress.com/2008/01/03/level1remove-unblockblock-file-attachments-in-ms-outlook/

But this still send the file with the email.

Regards
Jan

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the [ItemSend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865076(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Application class which is fired whenever an Microsoft Outlook item is sent, either by the user through an Inspector (before the inspector is closed, but after the user clicks the Send button) or when the Send method for an Outlook item, such as MailItem, is used in a program.

In the ItemSend event handler you can inspect the [Attachments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866435(v=office.15).aspx) property of the MailItem class which returns an Attachments object that represents all the attachments for the specified item.

The [Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868839(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Attachments class removes an object from the collection. Or you can use the [Delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866223(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Attachment class which deletes an object from the collection.

Note, you may need to check the [FileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867615(v=office.15).aspx) property before removing.